# Nix: go package in --pure mode still pointing to host's GOPATH

Tags: go, nix, nixos

I'm trying to run a nix shell with the go package to test a go program. However, to ensure reproducability, I do not want the go in nix-shell to point back to any host related path or info. So, I was advised to use the `--pure` flag in the command.

My final command looks like this:

```bash
$ nix-shell --pure -p go
```

Once the shell is live, I run `go env` and I see this:

```bash
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/HOSTUSERNAME/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/HOSTUSERNAME/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/HOSTUSERNAME/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/HOSTUSERNAME/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/nix/store/a7875alzpnr46z6mv4ssymfdwmvr6xbq-go-1.19.4/share/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/nix/store/a7875alzpnr46z6mv4ssymfdwmvr6xbq-go-1.19.4/share/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/run/user/1000/go-build3633664660=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I was expecting to install my Go project in a reproducible way without using the host's inherited `GOPATH` and other related environment variables.

Is there way to completely detach the host system's dependencies by Nix's go package installed in the shell and then test the Go Project?

Comment: A go installation does not store any environment variables. Are you certain you’re not just printing the defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when the environment variables `GOPATH`, `GOENV`, `GOMODCACHE`, &c. *are completely unset*, `go env` and related tools synthesize default values relative to `$HOME`.

Thus, if you want to test on a regular basis that your project doesn't have hidden dependencies on your home directory, you should wrap its build in a Nix derivation; assuming you're on a platform where Nix supports sandboxing, and that this feature is enabled, this will cause that build to be done in a sandbox with no access to your home directory.

See [gomod2nix](https://github.com/nix-community/gomod2nix) and more generally [the Go entry on nixos.wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Go) for guidance on building a derivation to wrap your program's build.

---

Also, note that `nix-shell --pure` doesn't create shells that are pure in every sense of the world: There's still a dependency on nixpkgs coming from your local channels. If you want to control that, you'll want a `shell.nix` or `flake.nix` that pins a specific nixpkgs revision.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the limitations of the `--pure` flag. I shall try to define my own .nix file in the Go project and take this forward.